# How can I get phpMyAdmin to display old data

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have this CodeIgniter 4 Project that I am running. It is running perfectly well on localhost but when I migrated it to the live server it is not displaying old data. I cross-checked the sql table on localhost and the one on the server and realized that it didn't set the ID as the PRIMARY KEY, which I did manually.

Now when I add data it shows perfectly but it doesn't show the old data when I query it on my CI project. Note that the old data is in the database but it is not being outputted in the CI view but any other data I insert is showing perfectly, yet I need the old data too.

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE `courseschedules` (
  `scheduleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `courseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `centerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trainerID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `startDate` date NOT NULL,
  `endDate` date NOT NULL,
  `createdBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modifiedBy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modifiedAt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `courseschedules` (`scheduleID`, `courseID`, `centerID`, `trainerID`, `startDate`, `endDate`, `createdBy`, `modifiedBy`, `createdAt`, `modifiedAt`) VALUES
(1, 16, 1, 48, '2021-02-15', '2021-02-20', 1, 0, '2021-02-13 17:35:08', NULL),
(251, 8, 1, 0, '2021-01-11', '2021-01-15', 1, 1, '2020-10-16 12:03:34', '2020-11-28 10:23:12'),
(252, 8, 1, 0, '2021-02-01', '2021-02-05', 1, 1, '2020-10-16 12:03:36', '2020-11-28 10:23:50'),
(253, 6, 1, 0, '2021-01-11', '2021-01-15', 1, 1, '2020-10-16 17:27:12', '2020-11-28 10:09:06'),
(254, 8, 1, 0, '2021-03-01', '2021-03-05', 1, 1, '2020-10-20 12:35:28', '2020-11-28 10:24:46'),
(255, 6, 1, 0, '2021-02-08', '2021-02-12', 1, 1, '2020-10-20 12:41:27', '2020-11-28 10:10:04'),
(256, 1, 1, 1, '2020-10-25', '2020-11-08', 1, 0, '2020-10-20 13:14:50', NULL),
```

After INSERT ...

```
--
ALTER TABLE `courseschedules`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`scheduleID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `courseschedules`
--
ALTER TABLE `courseschedules`
  MODIFY `scheduleID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2716;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Can someone point me where the problem might be, that I cannot be able to seen the old data.

**EDIT**
By 'OLD' data I mean the data that I had in my localhost before I transferred it to the live server...the data I inserted via sql:

Here is my Controller:

```
public function viewSchedules() {

        $data['cats'] = $this->$cats;
        $courseModel = new CourseModel();
        $data['courses'] = $courseModel->orderBy('courseName', 'ASC')->findAll();

        $courseId = $this->request->getVar('course');
        if ($courseId) {
            $dateFrom = $this->request->getVar('datefrom');
            $dateTo = $this->request->getVar('dateto');
            $data['courseid'] = $courseId;
            $data['datefrom'] = $dateFrom;
            $data['dateto'] = $dateTo;
            $data['fetched'] = 1;

            //fetch schedules here
            $scheduleModel = new ScheduleModel();
            $data['schedules'] = $scheduleModel->getCourseSchedules($courseId, $dateFrom, $dateTo);
            //var_dump($data['schedules']);


        }
```

While my Model looks like so:

```
public function getScheduleDetails($scheduleId){
  $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
  $builder = $db->table('courseschedules');

  $builder->select('*');
  $builder->join('courses', 'courseschedules.courseID = courses.courseID');
  $builder->join('durationtypes', 'courses.durationType = durationtypes.typeID');
  $builder->join('centers', 'courseschedules.centerID = centers.centerID');
  $builder->join('users', 'courseschedules.trainerID = users.userID');
  $query = $builder->getWhere(['scheduleID' => $scheduleId]);

  return $query->getRow();



}
public function getCourseSchedules($courseId,$dateFrom,$dateTo){
  $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
  $builder = $db->table('courseschedules');

  $builder->select('*');
  $builder->join('centers', 'courseschedules.centerID = centers.centerID');
  $builder->join('users', 'courseschedules.trainerID = users.userID');
  $query = $builder->getWhere(['courseID' => $courseId,'startDate'>=$dateFrom,'endDate'<=$dateTo]);

  return $query->getResult();

}
```

...and my view file:

```
<div class="col-md-4 alert-success">
<div class="pricing-v1 service-block-v3 service-block-blue service-in service-heading" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333; border-radius: 6px;">
                        <h4 class="service-heading">Course Description</h4>
                        <div class="" style="color: #fff;">
                        <small><b>Course Name:</b> <?php echo $schedule->courseName;      ?><br/></small>
                        <small><b>Course Duration:</b> <?php echo $schedule->duration.' '.$schedule->typeName;      ?><br/></small>
                        <small><b>Course Fee:</b>  <?php echo 'KShs '. $schedule->feeKshs.', USD '.$schedule->feeUsd;      ?><br/></small>
                        <small><b>Training Center:</b> <?php echo $schedule->centerName;   ?><br/></small>
                        <small><b>Trainer:</b> <?php echo $schedule->firstName.' '.$schedule->secondName.' '.$schedule->surName;   ?><br/></small>

                        <?php

                        $startDate=explode('-',$schedule->startDate);
                        $startDate=$startDate[2].'/'.$startDate[1].'/'.$startDate[0];

                        $endDate=explode('-',$schedule->endDate);
                        $endDate=$endDate[2].'/'.$endDate[1].'/'.$endDate[0];
                         ?>
                        <small><b>Start Date:</b> <?php echo $startDate;   ?><br/></small>
                        <small><b>End Date:</b> <?php echo $endDate;   ?><br/></small>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Wha two you mean by 'Old Data'?

Comment: Data is digital and cannot be "old". Just like Ramesh, I wonder what makes data old in your mind? To be more exact: Suppose it is the `createdAt` field. What happens then if you change that field to a newer date. Is it visible then? If so, then we would know what you mean by "old data".

Comment: We can't see what query the PHP is running, and we can't see the data you're talking about. This makes it impossible to answer the question

Comment: I have edited my question and explained what I meant by "OLD"...It is the imported data from localhost or the previously added data before changed the "scheduleID" to be the primary key. Before it wasn't displaying on view but after the change it could only show what was added after the edit but not before. I hope this is more clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. When you fetch the course schedules you are joining to two other tables (centers and users) at the same time. When you imported the data from localhost did you also important matching data into those tables, to match the center and course IDs in the courseschedules table?

Comment: @ADyson You have pointed me in the right direction. No, the data wasn't corresponding hence the problem I was facing.  I had to import a previously backed up schedules table for it to work. The problem was that I had made several posts with different data. Now it is working fine. Thank you.